# How to determine if a PropertyType is foreign key

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, foreign-keys, html-helper

I have the following class 'schakeling', generated with EF, representing a database table 'schakeling'. In the database 'id' is the primary key and 'plc_id' is a foreign key.

```cs
public partial class schakeling
{
    public schakeling()
    {
        this.verbruik = new HashSet<verbruik>();
    }

    public int id { get; set; }
    public int plc_id { get; set; }
    public string var_output { get; set; }
    public string omschrijving { get; set; }
    public int vermogen { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> status { get; set; }
    public Nullable<byte> hourOn { get; set; }
    public Nullable<byte> minuteOn { get; set; }
    public Nullable<byte> hourOff { get; set; }
    public Nullable<byte> minuteOff { get; set; }

    public virtual plc plc { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<verbruik> verbruik { get; set; }
}
```

I have a view class

```cs
public class SchakelingsListViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<schakeling> List { get; set; }
    public PagingInfo PagingInfo { get; set; }//Not relevant for this question
    //And some more properties...also not relevant
}
```

I have the following view (omitted some HTML for brevity)

```cs
@model PortalControl.ViewModels.SchakelingsListViewModel
<h2>Index</h2>
<table>
@foreach (var item in Model.List) {
    @Html.TableRowFor(item)
}
</table>
```

I have a generic html helper method TableRowFor because I want to be able to use the method on other domain entities generated with EF. The method generates simple table data.

```cs
public static MvcHtmlString TableRowFor<T>(this HtmlHelper helper, T obj)
{
    string controller = obj.GetType().BaseType.Name;
    string id = obj.GetType().GetProperty("id").GetValue(obj).ToString();

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("<tr>");
    sb.Append("<td>");
    sb.Append("<a href='" + controller + "/Edit/" + id + "'><img src='/Images/edit-icon.png' /></a>");
    sb.Append("<a href='" + controller + "/Details/" + id + "'><img src='/Images/details-icon.png' /></a>");
    sb.Append("<a href='" + controller + "/Delete/" + id + "'><img src='/Images/delete-icon.png' /></a>");
    sb.Append("</td>");

    foreach (var property in obj.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        //If statement below filters out the two virtual properties(plc, verbruik) of the schakeling class(as said, generated with EF), somewhat ugly but it works, better suggestions are welcome..
        if ((!property.PropertyType.Name.ToLower().Contains("icollection")) && (property.PropertyType.CustomAttributes.Count() != 0))
        {
            sb.Append("<td>");
            //if property is foreign key
                //sb.Append("<a href='" + correctControllerNameHere + "/Details/" + property.GetValue(obj) + "'><img src='/Images/details-icon.png' /></a>");
            //else
                //sb.Append(property.GetValue(obj));
            sb.Append("</td>");
        }
    }
    sb.Append("</tr>");
    return new MvcHtmlString(sb.ToString());
}
```

**The question I have is, I would like to create a link if a property is a foreign key.**

I have searched the internet but I am no expert in PropertyInfo, MetaDataClassType and other similar classes. Something like property.isForeign() would be lovely but anything that works will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get reference navigation properties from the Entity Framework conceptual model by this method:

```
IEnumerable<string> GetReferenceProperies<T>(DbContext context)
{
    var oc = ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext;
    var entityType = oc.MetadataWorkspace.GetItems(DataSpace.OSpace)
                       .OfType<EntityType>()
                       .FirstOrDefault (et => et.Name == typeof(T).Name);
    if (entityType != null)
    {
        foreach (NavigationProperty np in entityType.NavigationProperties
                .Where(p => p.ToEndMember.RelationshipMultiplicity
                                     == RelationshipMultiplicity.One
                         || p.ToEndMember.RelationshipMultiplicity
                                     == RelationshipMultiplicity.ZeroOrOne))
        {
            yield return np.Name;
        }
    }
}
```

It gets all navigation properties that have `0..1` at the end of the association, so that excludes collection navigation properties.

Now you can use the property names to get the matching `PropertyInfo`s and get the value of the properties.

Answer (score 2):

I got it working using your method, many thanks. For others, keep in mind this solution only works if you use a naming convention like mine(however, you can use the method of Gert as a guidance to pave the way for you're own solution):

- Give a foreign key the exact same name as the the name of the db table it refers to
- End the name with '_id'

Example:

You have a db table named user and want to create a new db table named bill. You want to refer a bill to an user using a FK, so in my situation I would name the FK user_id

Updated method TableRowFor:

```cs
public static MvcHtmlString TableRowFor<T>(this HtmlHelper helper, T obj)
{
    string controller = obj.GetType().BaseType.Name;
    string id = obj.GetType().GetProperty("id").GetValue(obj).ToString();

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("<tr>");
    sb.Append("<td>");
    sb.Append("<a href='" + controller + "/Edit/" + id + "'><img src='/Images/edit-icon.png' /></a>");
    sb.Append("<a href='" + controller + "/Details/" + id + "'><img src='/Images/details-icon.png' /></a>");
    sb.Append("<a href='" + controller + "/Delete/" + id + "'><img src='/Images/delete-icon.png' /></a>");
    sb.Append("</td>");

    List<string> referencePropertyList = GetReferenceProperies<T>(new NameOfDB()).ToList();
    foreach (var property in obj.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        //If statement below filters out the two virtual properties(plc, verbruik) of the schakeling class(as said, generated with EF), somewhat ugly but it works, better suggestions are welcome..
        if ((!property.PropertyType.Name.ToLower().Contains("icollection")) && (property.PropertyType.CustomAttributes.Count() != 0))
        {
            sb.Append("<td>");
            //if property is foreign key
            if (referencePropertyList != null && property.Name.Length >= 3 && referencePropertyList.Contains(property.Name.Substring(0, property.Name.Length - 3)))
                sb.Append("<a href='" + property.Name.Substring(0, property.Name.Length - 3 ) + "/Details/" + property.GetValue(obj) + "'>" + property.GetValue(obj) + "</a>");
            else
                sb.Append(property.GetValue(obj));
            sb.Append("</td>");
        }
    }
    sb.Append("</tr>");
    return new MvcHtmlString(sb.ToString());
}
```