# Find inverse property in Entity Framework class

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a type `a`, and a type `b`. Type `a` has an inverse property on type `b`, either by inference or by using `[InverseProperty]`.
Is it possible to find if a property on `a` has an inverse property somewhere on some type, and what this property name is? Preferably not the table and column names.

Thanks!

-Emil

Comment: You can find such properties using reflection

Comment: I think you can use [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22879214/861716) approach.

Comment: As Gert pointed out above: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22859430/how-to-determine-if-a-propertytype-is-foreign-key/22879214#22879214 is the correct answer.