# How to know if a column has a foreign key or not in entity framework

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, foreign-keys, entity

I'm new to entity framework,

To update a cell value, if the current field has a relationship with another sql table (entity class), 
I want to get that foreign table (to show in a daragridview etc. to select a new value from there)

But I've no idea how to do that? Can you give me a little example to go on please?

Additional:
Unfortinatelly I found a solution based on sql (ADO.NET) instead of EF, to check a column that has a relationship or not

and if has, with which table? 
the answer is following query for me;

```
select 
tp.name 'ParentTable', cp.name as ForeignInParent, tr.name 'ForeignTable', cr.name ForeignValueMember, fk.name FK_Name
FROM sys.foreign_keys fk
INNER JOIN     sys.tables tp ON fk.parent_object_id = tp.object_id
INNER JOIN     sys.tables tr ON fk.referenced_object_id = tr.object_id
INNER JOIN     sys.foreign_key_columns fkc ON fkc.constraint_object_id = fk.object_id
INNER JOIN     sys.columns cp ON fkc.parent_column_id = cp.column_id AND fkc.parent_object_id = cp.object_id
INNER JOIN     sys.columns cr ON fkc.referenced_column_id = cr.column_id AND fkc.referenced_object_id = cr.object_id
where tp.name='Payments' and cp.name = 'UserID'
```

I hope I can do this in EF

Comment: A good start would be to tag the appropriate Entity Framework *version* and to add an example of classes you're dealing with.

Comment: Consider to spend a few hours learning entity framework, for instance [Entity Framework Code First](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/what-is-code-first.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Imagine these two classes:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name{ get;set;}
    ....
}

public class Payment
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public int UserId {get; set;}
    ....
}
```

Now UserId is a foreign key:

1. If you are using entity framework (DB First) and classes are generated automatically then:

   a. each `User` will have `Payments` as its subitems when put a `.` after it:

   User user = SomeQuery...

you have `user.Payments`

b.Each payment has a user property:

```
Payment payment = somequery...
```

you can access the user who made the payment by `payment.User`

2. find the file with `.edmx` extension in your project. it shows a diagram of tables. each table has some fields, and at the bottom of fields, there is a `Navigation Properties` that shows Properties that are accessible because of the Foreign keys:

[image]

3. Find `.tt` files in your project. You can find auto-generated classes from the database there. all fields that are `virtual` are because of the foreign keys, as they are only navigational and do not really belong to that table (based on one-to-one, one-to-many, ... relations) they can be virtual Something, or virtual ICollecion.

**Edit:**

To check if a field is a foreign key in runtime as you stated in comments, you must use Reflection. [check out this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22859430/how-to-determine-if-a-propertytype-is-foreign-key).

Comment: it a nice explanations thaks for it, but what I need is basicly somethink like; if(Payment.UserID == isAforeignKeyColumn) { datagridview.datasource = MyEntityContext.Users.Local.ToBindingList(); }  how to write this in a correct way?

Comment: @AliCAKIL bey, if there is a foreign key, you can surely find it in classes in '.tt` file or by simply navigating with `.`

Comment: Mr. @Ashkan Mobayen Khiabani I beleive you dont understand me, I know to find column names ofter dot, But in rumtime user select a field randomly in a huge column list, so I have to check is that selected column has a relationship with other tables or not with an if statement.